# Zabbix scheduled reports can not calculate start time

Tags: zabbix

I don know what is happening or where is the root of this problem. I just installed the Zabbix Web Service and I created a new scheduled report. When I click the Test button when editing/creating a report I will obtain a report to my email account.
But when I save a scheduled report a will obtain an error in the Info column:

```
Cannot calculate report start time: [75] Value too large for defined data type
```

[image]

I tried also the 12h time format instead of the 24h time format (just to be sure) but not helped.

Here I am sending a scheduled report which I created:
[image]

I didn't found any information about this error so I assume there is a problem somewhere in my configuration.

My setup:

`Azure VM - Ubuntu server version 20.04.2 LTS`

`Zabbix Composed installation (Docker) version 5.4.0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solve it when I activate and set the property:

```
PHP_TZ=Europe\xxxxxx
```

inside the .env_web file and also set the same time zone into the zabbix UI and also to the host system.

After these changes I have never received this error again.